# wcfria concurrency clientside

Tags: concurrency, client, wcf-ria-services

I have a bunch of small lookup tables in my database.  It would be efficient to load them into local tables before processing the large  table.  Prefer to do this rather than a complicated join on the server-side and a new metadata type declaration in the middle layer.

So then this code demonstrates my complete lack of any understanding of how concurrency is supposed to work:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        concurrencyFlags = 0;
        context.Load<Priorite>(context.GetPrioritiesQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, prioritiesHaveBeenLoaded, null);
        context.Load<Projet>(context.GetProjectsQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, projectsHaveBeenLoaded, null);
        context.Load<TypeTicket>(context.GetTypeTicketsQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, typeTicketsHaveBeenLoaded, null);
        context.Load<Ticket>(context.GetOpenTicketsQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, ticketsHaveBeenLoaded, null);
        while (concurrencyFlags != everythingLoadedNow) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        proceedSingleThreadedFromHere();
    }
```

What is the proper way of doing this?  Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you block on the UI thread, the loading may not happen. Also, your UI becomes unresponsive. Instead, you should make the `concurrencyFlags` a field that can be used when the loads complete.

```
private int _concurrencyFlags;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _concurrencyFlags++;
    context.Load<Priorite>(context.GetPrioritiesQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, prioritiesHaveBeenLoaded, null);
    _concurrencyFlags++;
    context.Load<Projet>(context.GetProjectsQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, projectsHaveBeenLoaded, null);
    _concurrencyFlags++;
    context.Load<TypeTicket>(context.GetTypeTicketsQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, typeTicketsHaveBeenLoaded, null);
    _concurrencyFlags++;
    context.Load<Ticket>(context.GetOpenTicketsQuery(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, ticketsHaveBeenLoaded, null);
}
```

In each method, call `proceedSingleThreadedFromHere()`:

```
private void prioritiesHaveBeenLoaded(...)
{
    // Do work

    _concurrencyFlags--;
    proceedSingleThreadedFromHere();
}
```

Check for the value of the `_concurrencyFlags` before proceeding:

```
private void proceedSingleThreadedFromHere()
{
    if (_concurrencyFlags > 0) return;

    // Do work
}
```

This isn't thread-safe, but WCF RIA calls back on the UI thread by default. So in theory it should be good enough for a prototype.

Comment: Thanks Ed, you are correct, I just had to sit and think carefully for a while, then I got it.